# Invoke all methods of a prototype?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given a class like below I can `console.log` through all its `PropertyNames`

```
class Security {
  constructor(param: ParamType) {
    this.method1(param);
    ...
    this.methodN(param);
  }
  method1(param){...};
  ...
  methodN(param){...};
}

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Security.prototype).forEach( (value) => {
    console.log('Method: ', value);
    // value()?
});
```

My question is how to invoke all methods in the place of `// value()?`

Comment: Do you have `Security` instance created? You need to have an object in order to call its method.

Comment: Yes i have it created

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write something like this:

```
class Security {
  method1(param) {
    console.log("M1");
  }

  method2(param) {
    console.log("M2");
  }
}

function callAll() {
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Security.prototype).forEach(value => {
    if (value !== 'constructor' && typeof Security.prototype[value] === 'function')
        this[value]();
  });
}

callAll.apply(new Security())
```

Comment: One more question if i may:
Is it possible to distinguish how many parameters does a method have?

somewhat like this
                `// if 1 param
                this[value](passedParam1);
                // if 2 params
                this[value](passedParam1, passedParam2);`

Comment: in the code above it is up to you how or with how many parameters you call your functions, if you want to actually find out how the function was called you could check the `arguments` object https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp